# Making a wheel in QML using a flickable ListView

Tags: listview, qml

I have created a flickable ListView that snaps to a value. The problem is I can not figure out how to make it snap in the middle of the view in stead of the top. Is there any way to offset the place to snap  or some other way to solve this?

Currently it looks like this (where 14 is the snapped value):

[image]

but I want it to look like this, where 14 is the snapped value (I faked the view I want by dragging the wheel with the mouse):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [highlightRangeMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-listview.html#highlightRangeMode-prop) property of ListView.

Comment: This worked. Used highlightRangeMode. Used preferredHighlightBegin and preferredHighlightEnd to set the area where the "snap focus" should be.